# XCode Interface builder's navigation UINavigationItem has wrong height

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I just ran into this problem, that basically makes Interface Builder unusable for me.

I have a Detail View Controller, that should only work in Landscape mode. So I opened the storyboard in Xcode (latest public version, latest public Mac OS X), and picked the appropriate option to make it go into landscape.

However, this is what it shows:
[image]

It might not be directly obvious, but the navigation bar with "Detail" written on it is the wrong height. This is never how it appears on the device. This makes Interface Builder unusable, because I can't properly lay out / align etc. the UIWebView and UIImageView in this example (i.e., on the device it looks different than in Xcode, so I have no way of knowing how to lay it out in Xcode).

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug, is there a way to fix this (I tried changing the height of the navigation item, but it tells me "not applicable" when I open the size inspector)?

For reference, here is a screenshot showing how a navigation bar actually looks when you run an app, for you to appreciate the extent of the problem:

[image]

Comment: How high is your nav bar? It should be 44 points on iPad and 32 points on iPhone.

Comment: Xcode won't tell me, when I click on the nav bar and go to the size inspector it just says "Not Applicable"...

Comment: @Jim: but you can see the difference from the screenshots alone. The screens are the same size, and you can see that the two bars don't have the same height even though they should. It's most noticable when you check the amount of space above and below the "All Contacts" and "Detail"; there's more space above and below "Detail".

Comment: Yeah, your right. I see that. I don't have my laptop with me to check. Sorry.